# using api with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to api. I have drop down, a textbox and a button, If I select id from drop down and when I enter id in textbox and click on search button. All the columns related to that particular id should be shown. If I select name from drop down and input name then the search is filtered according to name. Help me please.

Api controller code:

```
public class EmployeeeeeController : ApiController { 
    // Get Employee By Id 
   public Employee Get(int id) { 
       using (VaruEntities db = new VaruEntities()) { 
           Employee empl = db.Employees.Find(id); 
           if (empl == null) { 
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)); 
           } 
           return empl; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller { 
    public ActionResult Details(int id) { 
        Employee ob = new Employee(); 
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
        var response = client.GetAsync("localhost:48721/api/Employeeeee?id="; + id).Result; 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { 
            ob = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result; 
        } 
        return View(ob); 
    } 
}
```

By using the above code I am only able to perform search on the basis of ID but **I want to perform multiple search**. The user can perform search on the basis of Id or Name or Mobile no.

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: public Employee Get(int id)
        {
            using (VaruEntities db = new VaruEntities())
            {
                Employee empl = db.Employees.Find(id);
                if (empl == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
                }
                return empl;
            }
        }
##In this I performed the search only on the basis of ID

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I need your support

Comment: Yes, we're here for the same, but we couldn't help you without minimal, complete and verifiable example as we have no idea about your issue.

Comment: //Api controller code
public class EmployeeeeeController : ApiController
    {
//  Get Employee By Id
        public Employee Get(int id)
        {
            using (VaruEntities db = new VaruEntities())
            {
                Employee empl = db.Employees.Find(id);
                if (empl == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
                }
                return empl;
            }
        }
}

Comment: //Controller code

 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Employee ob = new Employee();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:48721/api/Employeeeee?id=" + id).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ob = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result;
            }
            return View(ob);
        }
}

Comment: ## By using the above code I am only able to perform search on the basis of ID but I want to perform multiple search.The user can perform search on the basis of Id or Name or Mobile no.

Comment: if you have understood what I actually want then please once share the code

Comment: ok thanks for  the help

Comment: I put the code and question from your comments into the main body of the question. In the future, please use **edit** to clarify your question. (Some people might not read all comments).

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering) clauses to filter your data.

`Where` will return *all* entities that match the given filter criteria. If you only want to find a *single* entity, use `FirstOrDefault` (if you are expecting more than one potential match) or `SingleOrDefault` (if you are expecting at most a single match).

Extend your Web API action to take the additional query parameters. These parameters are optional, so the query ignores parameters that were left empty by utilizing the evaluation order of the [conditional OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)  `||`.

```
public Employee Get(int? id, string name, string mobileNo) { 
    using (VaruEntities db = new VaruEntities()) { 
        var ignoreIdFilter = !id.HasValue();
        var ignoreNameFilter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name);
        var ignoreMobileFilter =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mobileNo);

        var firstMatch = db.Employees.
            .Where(e => ignoreIdFilter || e.Id == id.Value)
            .Where(e => ignoreNameFilter  || e.Name == name)
            .Where(e => ignoreMobileFilter || e.MobileNo == mobileNo)
            .FirstOrDefault(); // will throw no exception if more than one record found

        if (firstMatch == null) { 
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)); 
        } 
        return firstMatch;
    }
}
```

Then pass the query parameters from your MVC controller to the Web API controller like you passed the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> By using the above code I am only able to perform search on the basis of ID but I want to perform multiple search.The user can perform search on the basis of Id or Name or Mobile no

In above comment you specify **OR** between Id, Name and Mobile.

So here we only need one parameter to convey value of either Id or Name or MobileNo.

1) Modify your Details action method in `HomeController` like

```
public ActionResult Details(int search)
{
    Employee ob = new Employee();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetAsync("localhost:48721/api/Employeeeee?search=" + search).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ob = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result;
    }
    return View(ob);
}
```

In above method we just pass a `search` parameter to `Details` action method.

You should pass any value like `Id` or `Name` or `MobileNo` in this parameter.

2) Modify your `Get` api method in `EmployeeController` like

```
public Employee Get(string search)
{
    using (VaruEntities db = new VaruEntities())
    {
         int id = 0, tempId = 0;
         if (int.TryParse(search, out tempId))
            id = Convert.ToInt32(search);    

         Employee empl = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == id ||                                                                                                  
                      x.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(search.Trim().ToLower()) || 
                      x.MobileNo.Trim().ToLower().Contains(search.Trim().ToLower())).SingleOrDefault();

        if (empl == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return empl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Varsha Babani, view the answer might be it help you :)